# Use API Response from a website on a Google Assistant Action

Tags: actions-on-google, diagflow

For the context, I'm using public transport everyday. My city got an app to check the trains/buses and even a public API.
With Assistant Snapshot on my phone it tells me at which time I should leave for work, but I don't have precise timetable (especially for buses) and it's only for work.
At some point Maps used to give me the next buses at my closest station but it's gone (i don't know why)

So I decided to build an Assistant Action to ask for the next bus/subway/train for a particular line, and wanted to use their public API for this. The first time ask the user their favorites lines/stations for example.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can start with a [conversational action](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/build) and use a webhook to call their public API and return the results in rich response [like a table](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts-rich#table_cards).